# Como remover tabela dos resultados de um find() do CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Tenho 3 tabelas relacionadas: `Usuario`, `Movimentacao` e `Grupo`

Estou usando:

```
$usuarios = $this->Usuario->find('all',array(
    'recursive' => 1,
    'fields' => "Usuario.id, Usuario.nome, Usuario.email"
    'order' => array('Usuario.nome ASC')
));
```

Porém, o `recursive => 1` está trazendo as três tabelas. Se coloco 0, retorna apenas Usuario. Eu preciso retornar apenas Usuario e Grupo, pois, trazendo Movimentacao, a query fica lenta demais. Como faço pra eliminar Movimetacao da query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode desassociar o outro model temporariamente:

```
$this->Usuario->unbindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Movimentacao')));
```

(Substitua `hasAndBelongsToMany` pelo tipo de relacionamento que está usando.)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Ao dar `unbind`, você retira totalmente o relacionamento deste model durante a execução.

Recomendo fazer a seleção de dados de 2 maneiras:

Para associações diretas, Você pode passar o recursive em conjunto com o fields e limitando assim os dados retornados. Por exemplo:

```
$result = $this->Usuario->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Usuario.status' => 'ativo'),
    'recursive' => 1,
    'fields' => array('Usuario.nome', 'Grupo.nome')
));
```

Para associações profundas utilizar o Containable Behavior (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

Exemplo de utilização em um controller:

```
$this->Usuario->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$result = $this->Usuario->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Usuario.status' => 'ativo'),
    'contain' => array('Grupo')
));
```